# Integrals of the form $e^{-A\sqrt{x^2+B}}$

Tags: integration, plane-geometry

I now have an integral which can be abbreviated to the form：

$$
e^{-Ar}
$$

where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. I need to perform the xy area integral of this function

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy e^{-A\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} 
$$

I found a lot of integrals in the form $e^{-A\sqrt{x}}$ on the Internet, but there is no integral in the form $e^{-A\sqrt{x^2+B}}$.

I hope to know how I should operate on this type of integral, since the actual function is more complicated than this one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think using polar coordinates for this one seems like a better idea

Comment: Perhaps you may try series expansion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral in Cartesian coordinates looks fairly complicated, to say the least. If we change to polar coordinates, the integral becomes

$$ I = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\infty} r e^{-A\sqrt{r^2+z^2}} dr d\theta$$

Now, substitute $ r^2+z^2 = v$ and proceed. It will become an integral of the form $e^{-A\sqrt v}$, which you have said you know how to evaluate. Note that $z$ behaves like a constant.

Comment: Yes, I made the problem seem complicated, I will try polar coordinates, thank you for your answer

Comment: How are the bounds changing? The new integral obtained seems $\theta$ independent .

Comment: Is my result below correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compute $$I=\int e^{-A\sqrt{x^2+B}}\,dx$$ but do not plan to integrate it with a lower bound equal to $0$, you could expand as a series.

Assuming $x>0$, you will have
$$e^{-A\sqrt{x^2+B}}=e^{-Ax}\Bigg(1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {P_n(x)}{x^{2n+1}}\, B^n\Bigg)$$ with
$$P_n(x)=\frac {-2 (n-1) (2 n-3)\, P_{n-1}+A^2\,P_{n-2} } {4 n(n-1) }$$ with $P_0(x)=1$ and $P_1(x)=-\frac{A}{2 x}$.

This would lead to a series of exponential integral functions.

For example, for the term in $B^2$
$$\int \frac{A e^{-A x} (A x+1)}{8 x^3}\,dx=
-\frac{A}8 \Bigg(\frac{A x+1}{2 x^2}\,e^{-A x}  +\frac{A^2}{2}\,\,  \text{Ei}(-A x)  \Bigg)$$

Answer (score 0):

I want to "complete" the accepted answer of Scipio.
$$\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy e^{-A\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\\
&\text{(Change to polar coordinates.)}\\
&= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\infty} r e^{-A\sqrt{r^2+z^2}} dr d\theta\\
&\text{(Let $v=r^2+z^2.$)}\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{2\pi} \int_{z^2}^{\infty} e^{-A\sqrt{v}} dv d\theta\\
&=\pi\int_{z^2}^{\infty} e^{-A\sqrt{v}} dv\\
&(\text{Let }u=A\sqrt v)\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{A^2}\int_{Az}^\infty ue^{-u}du\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{A^2}\Gamma(2,Az)
\end{align}$$
where $\Gamma(s,x)$ is the [incomplete gamma function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) which is a well-known special function.

Comment: In fact $\int_{Az}^\infty ue^{-u}du=(1+Az)e^{-Az}$.

Comment: @J.G. Okay. But my result is correct. Right? Thanks. (,,>﹏<,,)

Comment: Sure, but there's no need to use the incomplete gamma for $s\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: @J.G. Yes. (,,>_<,,)

Comment: Certainly correct, but one can arrive at the answer by simply using integration by parts. Thanks for completing the answer, though!